# JavaScript errors

Tags: javascript, errors, migration

Recently I just moved my website to new server. it was working fine with the old server. but now after i changed to new server the wordpress layout is collapsed. when i saw the console i have seen this error(refer the image). it also adding x to the script it make the error coming. please help me with this.[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks like your code is messed up, with the `<script>`-tag inside the JavaScript function. Are you sure the files are copied as-is?

Comment: yes all the files are there, but i can't able to figure out what is the issue

Answer (score -1):

Try & paste this below code your active theme functions.php file

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_jquery_fix', 100 );
function load_jquery_fix() {
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
        wp_register_script( 'jquery', ( "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js" ), false, '1.11.3' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    }
}
```

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?

Comment: I have copy pasted above code, but still i have the errors